# ember find() keeps making api call even after I've stored it in DS.Store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model with a custom adapter. I've got my adapter populating the application store but when my component calls `find('model')` it does another server request -- which I do not want. The docs said that if something's recorded in the store, then it will get it from cache.

```
SongAdapter = ApplicationAdapter.extent
    data = somePayload
    new Ember.RSVP.Promise (resolve, reject) =>
        path = 'some/endpoint/songs'
        myPOST(path, data, @, options).then (data) ->
             _.each data.songs, (entity) ->
                 entity.id = entity.songId
                 store.push('song', store.normalize('song', entity))
                 Ember.run(null, resolve, data)
            , (jqXHR) ->
                 jqXHR.then = null
                 Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR)
```

When my component loads I fetch the initial songs like this:

```
getSongHistory: Ember.on 'didInsertElement', ->
     @store.find('song').then (data) =>
         @set('songHistory', data.get('content'))
```

I'm missing something. I thought that `find()` was supposed to **search the cache first**, then if empty delegate to the `findAll()` method in the adapter. What am I missing?

Comment: I think ``all()`` is what you need if you want to see what is in the store. So basically I check if that is empty first and if it is I do the ``find('song')`` which delegates to my ``findAll()`` in my adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` with a single argument delegates to your adapters `findAll()` method which will always make a request. So my solution was to first check if the store contained any records. If it didn't then call `find()`. **If there were records, get them using `all()` -- which doesn't make a network request** -- and set the data to the array in your component.

```
getSongHistory: Ember.on 'didInsertElement', ->
    if @store.all('song').content.length is 0
        @store.find('song').then (data) =>
            @set('songHistory', data.get('content'))
    else
        @set('songHistory', @store.all('song').content)
```

**I hope this pattern makes sense.**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Ember Data:

If you check out the code for `find` [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.16.1/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L404), you can see that when you call it with one argument (in your case `store.find('song')`), it delegates to `findAll` which in turn delegates to `fetchAll`, which states:

```
/**
    This method returns a fresh collection from the server, regardless of if there is already records
    in the store or not.
    @method fetchAll
    @param {String or subclass of DS.Model} type
    @return {Promise} promise
  */
```

The `find` documentation is bit misleading and should probably be changed.